# Makefile with multiple rules sharing same recipe with patternrules?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I want to remove the duplication of recipe in a makefile like the following

```
SHELL := /bin/bash
a_% : a1_% a2_%       
          cat $^ > $@                                                                                                                             
b_% : b1_% b2_%   %_b3                                                                                                                         
          cat $^ > $@
```

However the following does not work. I guess the trick in [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11441084/makefile-with-multiples-rules-sharing-same-recipe) does not work with pattern rules.

```
SHELL := /bin/bash
a_% : a1_% a2_%       
b_% : b1_% b2_%   %_b3                                                                                                                         
a_% b_%:
          cat $^ > $@
```

Any suggestions ? ( In my original makefile, recipe duplication is occurring in 4 targets, and each of those take 3 substitutions, so I can't unroll the targets)

--EDIT--
I realized that one way to solve this was the following.

```
CMD1 = cat $^ > $@
a_% : a1_% a2_%       
         $(CMD1)
b_% : b1_% b2_%   %_b3
        $(CMD1)
```

Comment: There is no way to combine pattern rules. The best you can do is as you've done: use the same variable for the recipe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this does what you asked for:

```
SHELL := /bin/bash

define STUFF
$(1)_%: $(1)1_% $(1)2_% $(2)
    cat $$^ > $$@
endef

$(eval $(call STUFF,a))
$(eval $(call STUFF,b,%_b3))
```

How this works:

1. The general form of the rule is defined as `STUFF`. (You'd obviously want a better name in your own Makefile.) Note the doubling of dollar signs in `$$^` and `$$@`. This protects them from evaluation when `$(call ...)` is executed. `$(1)` and `$(2)` will be replaced by `$(call ...)` with positional arguments.
2. `$(call STUFF,a)` "calls" `STUFF` with `$(1)` set to the string `a` and `$(2)` set to the empty string.  The return value is:

   ```
   a_%: a1_% a2_% 
       cat $^ > $@
   ```

   Note how one `$` was stripped from the remaining variables.
3. $(eval ...) evaluates the return value obtained in the previous step as if that string had been put in the Makefile. So it creates the rule.

Steps 2 and 3 also happen for the `b` files. It is similar to what happens for the `a` files except that this time `$(2)` is set to the string `%_b3`.

This is essentially the method I've used in the past to avoid duplication of rules for cases where the rules were rather complex. For the *specific* case you show in your question, I'd use the shared command variable you mention in your question.