# mark Make target as not directly callable

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

**How can I mark Make targets as "uncallable" or "do not call this target directly"?**

For example,

```
common:
    touch $(VAR)  # VAR is expected to be set

foo: VAR = this
foo: common

bar: VAR = that
bar: common
```

I do not want users to do the following:

```
make common
```

**Is there a Make idiom to mark `common` as uncallable?**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I make a target "private" in GNU make for internal use only? OR: how to best enforce target-specific variable-values?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26063839/how-can-i-make-a-target-private-in-gnu-make-for-internal-use-only-or-how-to)

Answer (score 1):

you can use a specific pattern for "private targets" and check for this pattern

also targets starting with "_" seem to be not listed in auto completion

```
ifeq ($(findstring _,$(MAKECMDGOALS)),_)
$(error target $(MAKECMDGOALS) is private)
endif

.PHONY: public-target
public-target: _private-target
public-target:
    echo "public target"

.PHONY: _private-target
_private-target:
    echo "private target"
```

Answer (score 0):

The following would work

```
ifeq ($(MAKECMDGOALS),common)
$(error do not call common directly)
endif
```

However, writing the `ifeq ($(MAKECMDGOALS), ...)` is difficult for targets like

```
%-$(VERSION).tar:
     # create the final .tar file
```

Comment: I was hoping for something more succinct.  Something like the `.PHONY` label that can be applied to targets.  For example, may something like `.INDIRECT` to mark the target as only indirectly callable (or not directly callable).

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing akin to `.PHONY` that keeps a target from being built via the command line.  You could do this though:

```
common:
        $(if $(VAR),,$(error You must run 'make foo' or 'make bar'))
        touch $(VAR)
```